# Python Pandas: How to take categorical average of a column?

Tags: pandas

for a given dataframe as follows:

```
1 a 10
2 a 20
3 a 30
4 b 10
5 b 100
```

where column 1 is index, column 2 is some categorical value and column 3 is a number. I want categorical mean over column 2, which should look something like this:

```
a 20
b 55
```

The value for a is calculated as

```
(10+20+30)/3 = 20
```

The value for b is calculated as

```
(10+100)/2 = 55
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df
   a  b    c
0  1  a   10
1  2  a   20
2  3  a   30
3  4  b   10
4  5  b  100

df1 = df.groupby('b')['c'].mean().reset_index()
print df1
   b   c
0  a  20
1  b  55

print df1.c.max()
55
print df1.c.min()
20
```

Comment: Is it possible to also get the max and min value from the result? Thanks for the answer !
Edited - Got it! never mind !